# Chat Program with server and client, socket programming in C

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I'm meant to write a Simple Chat Program using sockets with client.c and server.c
here are the requirements I'm given:

Server:

- Accepts one connection
- Chats with the client by accepting a message first and then sending a user-inputted message.
- If the client message is "end" the Server will close the connection.
- Otherwise, continue exchanging messages forever.
  Client:
- Connects to the Server
- Starts chatting by sending the user input string to the server, followed by displaying the server response to the user.
- If the user enters "end", the client will send it to the server and terminate the connection.

Here is the code that I came up with for server.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    unsigned short port;
    struct sockaddr_in Client_info;
    socklen_t Client_Info_Len;

    struct sockaddr_in Server_info;
    int Socket_Serv_FD, Socket_Client_FD;
    int result;

    char message[100];
    char Message_From_Client[100];

    port = 23232;

    printf("Server initiating connection ... \n");

    // create socket
    Socket_Serv_FD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    // check for failure
    if(Socket_Serv_FD < 0){
        printf("Socket creation failed.");
        return -1;
    }

    // binding information
    Server_info.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Server_info.sin_port = port;
    Server_info.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;


    // bind with port to the socket
    result =  bind(Socket_Serv_FD, (struct sockaddr *)&Server_info, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    if(result < 0){
        printf("Binding socket failed.");
        return -1;
    }

    // listen for connections on socket
    result = listen(Socket_Serv_FD, 0);
    if(result < 0){
        printf("Listen socket failed");
        return -1;
    }

        // accept when a connection occurs
        Socket_Client_FD = accept(Socket_Serv_FD, (struct sockaddr *)&Client_info, &Client_Info_Len);
        if(Socket_Client_FD < 0){
            printf("Socket connection failed.");
            return -1;
        }

    while(1){
        // read message from client
        result = read(Socket_Client_FD, &Message_From_Client, sizeof(Message_From_Client));
        if(result < 0){
            printf("Socket failed.");
            return -1;
        }

        printf("Message from client >> %s \n", Message_From_Client);

        // close socket when user enters 'end'!
        if(strcmp(Message_From_Client, "end") == 0){
            printf("Closing connection ... \n");
            break;
        }

        // prompt for message to send to client
        printf("Type a message to the client : ");
        scanf("%[^\n]", message);
        //fgets(message, 100, stdin);

        // send message to client
        result = write(Socket_Client_FD, &message, strlen(message));
        if(result < 0){
            printf("Message failed.");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    close(Socket_Serv_FD);
    close(Socket_Client_FD);
    return 0;
}
```

and here is my client.c code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    struct sockaddr_in Server_info;
    int Socket_FD;
    int result;
    
    char message[100];
    char Message_From_Server[100];
    
    int port = 23232;
    
    printf("Initiating connection ... \n");
    
    // create a socket
    Socket_FD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(Socket_FD == -1){
        printf("Socket creation failed.");
        return -1;
    }   
    
    // bind information
    Server_info.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Server_info.sin_port = port;
    Server_info.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    
    // listen for connections
    result = connect(Socket_FD, (struct sockaddr *)&Server_info, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    if(result < 0){
        printf("Connect socket failed.");
        return -1;
    } 
        
    while(1){
        // get input message from user
        printf("Type a message to server or 'end' to close connection : ");
        scanf("%[^\n]", message);
        //fgets(message, 100, stdin);

        // send to server
        result = write(Socket_FD, &message, sizeof(message));
        if(result < 0){
            printf("Message failed.");
            return -1;
        }
        
        // close socket when user enters 'end'!
        if(strcmp(message, "end") == 0){
            printf("Closing connection ... ");
            close(Socket_FD);
            return 0;
        }
        
        // receive from server
        result = read(Socket_FD, &Message_From_Server, strlen(Message_From_Server));
        if(result < 0){
            printf("Message failed.");
            return -1;
        }
        
        printf("Message from server >> %s \n", Message_From_Server);
        
    }
}
```

When I run the program it seems to work at first, prompting client for a message to server and then sending that  message to the server once I hit enter. However, after I try to send a message back to the client from the server the code breaks and outputs an infinite loop in the terminal. It's meant to be a steady back-and-forth where the client and server sends messages to each other until the client enters 'end'.

Here is the output I'm receiving ::

first i start the program and it prompts client side for a msg
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gHqt.png)
next i type the msg 'hello server' and press enter, server receives msg fine and is prompted to send msg back
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeS4Q.png)
next i type the msg 'hello client' and press enter, but this is the resulting output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3lqD.png)

thank you in advance for any help (:

Comment: If `read()` returns -1 you should print the error number or message, and if it returns 0 the peer has disconnected so you should close the socket and stop reading: this also means that your "end" message is redundant. You can't assume you received an entire message in a single read, and you can't assume null-termination unless you put it there, which you didn't, *and* you got the entire message.

Comment: You also have `read(Socket_FD, &Message_From_Server, strlen(Message_From_Server)`, which makes no sense whatsoever. You don't know the length until after you've read it, and the message length has nothing to do with the space available to read it into. It should be `read(Socket_FD, &Message_From_Server, sizeof Message_From_Server`, as in the server code.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the strlen to sizeof in each occurrence, however I don't really understand the first comment. Isn't checking if the result from read = -1 to make sure there wasn't an error, while the user inputting 'end' means they manually close the chat? how should I fix it if it's not the correct way to prompt the user to end messaging

Comment: If you get an error, print the error. I don't see how I can put it any more clearly, or how I didn't say that the first time. The client doesn't have to send `"end"`, just close the socket. Furthermore the one place where you *should* use `strlen()`, you aren't: `write(Socket_FD, &message, sizeof(message))` should be `write(Socket_FD, &message, strlen(message)+1)`, the +1 being to include the trailing null byte.

Comment: oh, i see, thank you!
so I should use sizeof() with reading, because we won't know the length until after it's read, but we do know the length when writing so we use strlen?
Just repeating the information so I know I'm understanding the reasoning (:

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use scanf to read your input. I see you tried (maybe?) with fgets but apparently with no success since it's commented out. Now you should remember that fgets reads up to "size"-1 characters and the newline (\n) character too so you need to remove it from the string. There are different ways to achieve this, the one I used was

```
message[strcspn(message, "\n")] = 0;
```

Meanwhile scanf will only parse whatever matches it's format specifier, everything else is left in the buffer for you to manage. As soon as I tried to run the code with scanf I got an infinite loop just like you did.
Now, I want to also mention that instead of using write/read I used send/recv which should be nearly identical to write/read when a 0 flag is used in the function call, maybe it will be different for you.
Namely, in client.c

```
result = write(Socket_FD, &message, sizeof(message));
```

becomes

```
result = send(Socket_FD, message, sizeof(message),0);
```

and

```
result = read(Socket_FD, &Message_From_Server, strlen(Message_From_Server);
```

becomes

```
result = recv(Socket_FD, Message_From_Server, sizeof(Message_From_Server),0);
```

Same changes in server.c
Note that the above changes just allows your program to run as you expected initially, you still need to think about everything else because there are countless ways this program can crash or behave in a non intended way. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I implemented these changes and no longer have that infinite loop. There is, however, another issue:
I'm able to send an initial message from client to server, and then a message from server to client in reply
But then when I try to send a second message from the client to server again it is not received and nothing happens after I press enter. if i enter 'end' the connection is closed on client end but again, not received on server end so nothing happens there

Comment: "Maybe it will be different for you": no it won't.

Comment: I was using read and write because that's what my professor told me ("To send data use the write system call. The same system call as used with pipes and files.") we havent learned about recv and send yet! maybe he will teach that next...

Comment: I got it! Thank you again for the help (: